# vRA Windows machine creation does not return host name/addr before moving to chef provisioner block

Tags: chef-infra, terraform, vmware, winrm

When creating a Windows machine in vRA, Terraform will move on to the Chef Provisioner block before it has acquired the IP/FQDN of the new machine to pass into the provisioner.

Terraform v0.11.14
+ provider.vra7 v0.2.0

I've tried everything I can get my hands on from the internet; loca-exec'ing knife bootstrap, using a depends_on attribute, setting a sleep timer, nothing seems to work.

```
resource "vra7_deployment" "terraform-1" {
  count             = "${var.server_count}"
  description       = "deployment via terraform"
  reasons           = "because it's awesome"
  catalog_item_name = "${var.vra_cat_item_name}"
  wait_timeout      = "1800"

  provisioner "chef" {
    # This is for chef_server to talk to the node
    connection {
      type = "winrm"
      user = "${var.KT_USER}"
      password = "${var.KT_PASS}"
      insecure = true
    }

    # This is for TF to talk to the chef_server
    server_url = "${var.chef_server_url}" 
    node_name  = "terraform-chef-test"
    run_list   = [ ]
    user_name  = "${var.chef_user_name}"
    user_key   = "${file(var.chef_user_pem)}"
    recreate_client = true
    fetch_chef_certificates = true
    environment = "_default"
    ssl_verify_mode = false
    version = "12"
  }
}
```

error:

```
vra7_deployment.terraform-1: Still creating... (21m20s elapsed)
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef): Connecting to remote host via WinRM...
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef):   Host:
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef):   Port: 5985
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef):   User: engineering
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef):   Password: true
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef):   HTTPS: false
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef):   Insecure: true
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef):   NTLM: false
vra7_deployment.terraform-1 (chef):   CACert: false

* vra7_deployment.terraform-1: interrupted - last error: unknown error Post http://:5985/wsman: dial tcp :5985: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The key was understanding that my instance of vRA is set up so that the VMs are called `vSphere_Machine_1`. It's right there in the UI, as `Component Name`.

There were definitely some mental leaps involved, and I'm sure I had to have seen all the other examples and made all the mistakes i did in order for my brain to put it all together at that moment. Whatever the mechanism, this code now WORKS:

```
# in resource block
resource_configuration {
    vSphere_Machine_1.name = ""
  }

...

# in provisioner block
    connection {
      host = "${self.resource_configuration.vSphere_Machine_1.name}"
     ....
}
```

Now, of course, on to the next brick wall... but I figured this out. And I intend to pay it forward to the community.

For others coming to this with the same question, you are looking for the Component Name in your vRa item's machine listing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`var.chef_server_url` is a terraform variable, not an output of `vra7_deployment.terraform-1`.

if `var.chef_server_url` is not set and passed to the provisioner with no value, then the provisioner connection will not work

Comment: var.chef_server_url is set in variables.tf and I don’t think that’s the problem. I get same result if I hardcode it. If you see in the terraform output, it’s trying to connect to the new node, not to the chef server. I could of course be mistaken.